# AngularJs FilterBy property a in array A, where a exists in array B

Tags: angularjs

I am using [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#filterby) and I want to loop the collection A and only display items where A.a exists in array B.

```
A = [{a:'mouse', c:'Tom'}, {a:'cat', c:'Jerry'}];
B = ['cat', 'dog'];
```

Then, I want something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in A | filterBy: ['item.a'] : B">
    {{item.c}}
</div>
```

Would return: `<div>Jerry</div>` because cat is in B. I imagine that I can achieve this with [pick](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#pick), but was wondering if I can do this with filterBy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if using lodash will do for you and you are not married to the filter idea. here is a quick solution.

define on the scope a function that gets the selected ones and bind that to the ng-repeat:

```
$scope.commonItems = function(){
   return _.filter(A, function(itemA){ return _.includes(B, itemA.a) })
}
```

and then:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in commonItems()">
    {{item.c}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I do use lodash, so will try this out (after lunch).